# Call is stuck between exchanging encryption keys on Telegram desktop App

Tags: mx-linux

My distro is MX-Linux 21 KDE. I have installed the Telegram desktop from their website.

However, I cannot make or accept new calls on this app. When the receiver or I accept the call, the "exchanging encryption process" takes a couple of seconds, and during that, the call drops all of a sudden. I am clueless about the problem. It seems the call is stuck between the exchange of encryption process.

Does anyone have a clue regarding this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check your firewall. That happens when Telegram cannot open all the ports it needs. If you are behind a proxy, check that it is socks5 **and** it handles UDP (sshd's socks5 proxy doest not seem to), otherwise calls do not work (for me at least).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, how to be sure which rule might be causing the issue? And I did not get what you wanted to say by this, "If you are behind a proxy." Would you please give a thorough explanation? Thanks in advance.